# Ошибки при билде apk(android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable)

Tags: java, android-studio

Чистая студия, приложение стартует всё нормально работает. Но каждый раз в любом проекте всегда одна и та же ошибка

> Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
>
> 05-21 21:38:00.270 21270-21270/com.alexfix.towerdefense W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 141 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
>
> 05-21 21:38:00.270 21270-21270/com.alexfix.towerdefense D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c

Может кто знает как с этим справится?

Comment: ripple-эффект доступен только с API 21

Comment: Я его нигде не использую почему он выдает эту ошибку?

Comment: компилятор должен ссылаться на строку, которая вызывает эту ошибку, что в ней?

Comment: Поэтому и пишу тут, не ссылается ни на какую строку просто выдает это сообщение красным при компиляции.

Comment: Видимо используете `AppCompatImageHelper`, который ссылается на рипл

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду это ?                                                                   
`import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;import android.os.Bundle;`
`import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TableRow;  ` Это все импорты которые я делаю ImageHelper нету